# Hive- issue with Create Table with column have space

Tags: sql, hive

Will need some advice. In HIVE DB is it possible to create table with column have space as below

```
CREATE TABLE TEST2("Kod ASS" String)
```

get an error as below

> Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:19 cannot recognize input near '"Kod ASS"' 'String' ')' in column specification
>   SQLState:  42000
>   ErrorCode: 40000

Answer (score 6, accepted):

show manual about column names:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL

> In Hive 0.12 and earlier, only alphanumeric and underscore characters are allowed in table and column names.
>
> In Hive 0.13 and later, column names can contain any Unicode character (see HIVE-6013). Any column name that is specified within
>   backticks (`) is treated literally. Within a backtick string, use
>   double backticks (``) to represent a backtick character. Backtick
>   quotation also enables the use of reserved keywords for table and
>   column identifiers.
>
> To revert to pre-0.13.0 behavior and restrict column names to alphanumeric and underscore characters, set the configuration property
>   hive.support.quoted.identifiers to none. In this configuration,
>   backticked names are interpreted as regular expressions. For details,
>   see Supporting Quoted Identifiers in Column Names.

Comment: Where I can set the hive.support.quoted.identifiers? Do you have any example?

Answer (score 0):

CREATE TABLE DB_Name.Table_name (
`First name`  VARCHAR(64), `Last name`  VARCHAR(64), `Location id`  VARCHAR(64) , age INT, gpa DECIMAL(3,2)) CLUSTERED BY (age) INTO 2 BUCKETS STORED AS ORC;

OR

CREATE TABLE TEST2(`Kod ASS` String) STORED AS TEXTFILE;

You can use   and put column name inside.
I hope both worked for you.